# User input selects dictionary value and store it as a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently working on a script that calculates the costs of an electric engine.

For that, I have to take into consideration the fees for each kWh of electricity spent. There are 5 possible fees, which I've stored in a dictionary, along with their respective prices.

I want the user to type the current fee, and from that, store the price as an independent variable, so I can multiply the kWh price by the engine's total running time.

The part of the script where the user chooses the fee is this one:

```
    flags = {
        "Green Flag" : "0.19829",
        "Yellow Flag" : "0.22818",
        "Red Flag 1" : "0.26329",
        "Red Flag 2" : "0.29624",
        "Drought Flag" : "0.34029"
    }

    print("CEMIG's power consumption flags are: \n")

    for x in flags:
        print (x, "\n", "-" * 20, "\n")

    def flag():
        while True:
            print("What's the current flag at the farm's location? \n")
            global choose_current_flag
            choose_current_flag = input(">: ")

            if choose_current_flag in flags:
                print(f"Right, so we are in {choose_current_flag}. \n")

                for value in flags[choose_current_flag]:
                    global cost_kwh
                    cost_kwh = value
                    print(cost_kwh)
            else:
                print("Be sure you've inserted the correct flag. \n")
```

Currently, the script gives me the following:

```
    "CEMIG's power consumption flags are: 
    
    Green Flag 
     -------------------- 
    
    Yellow Flag 
     -------------------- 
    
    Red Flag 1 
     -------------------- 
    
    Red Flag 2 
     -------------------- 
    
    Drought Flag 
     -------------------- 
    
    What's the current flag at the farm's location? 
    
    >: Green Flag
    Right, so we are in Green Flag. 
    
    0
    .
    1
    9
    8
    2
    9"
```

I understand why this is happening. The value is a string, so the for loop will iterate through every character.

Using the value as a bool did not help me, since I'm not able to iterate through it anyways.

I've tried dozens of alternatives, ready many answers here and elsewhere, but I can't find a way to get a user input to store the value as a variable.

Comment: What's there to iterate through? It seems to me your `flags[choose_current_flag]` is supposed to be single value

Answer (score 0):

So, here in your code,
Instead of iterating and using this snippet :

```
for value in flags[choose_current_flag]:
global cost_kwh
cost_kwh = value
print(cost_kwh)
```

Use this :

```
print(flags[choose_current_flag])
```

This is used to get the **value** of the specific **key** in the python **dictionary**.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: That's almost what I wanted! Double's answer was exactly what I needed, but it's something very similar!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

flags holds string values, and on top of that I don't think you want a loop at all.

I think you are looking for...

```
cost_kwh = float(flags[choose_current_flag])
```

... in place of your loop

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).